# How to make client request to external server avoiding cache using aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

We are using aiohttp to make multiple requests to various website vendors to grab their latest data.

Some of the content providers serve the data from a cache. Is it possible to request the data from the server directly? We have tried to pass in the `headers` parameter with no luck.

```
async def fetch(url):
    global response
    headers = {'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=headers, proxy="OUR-PROXY") as response:
            return await response.read()
```

The goal is to get the `last-modified date header`, which is not provided from the cache request.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what cache are you talking about and what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some additional variable with dynamic value to URL (e.g. timestamp).
This will prevent caching on the server side even if it ignores Cache-Control.

Example:
from: https://example.com/test
to: https://example.com/test?timestamp=20180724181234

Comment: Does the value need to be unique each time you make the call? For example we make 100 calls a day, can we append the same value in the URL, or must it be different to bypass the cache ?

Comment: Yes, just different (each time unique) to bypass the cache.

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Then try to send requests in different sessions.